New manual truck, when it stalls I can't restart it if is still moving
MITSUBISHI Triton (m200)​ latest model(2023) manual transmission, diesel. Rarely happened with other cars but with this one I often stall by inserting the wrong gear. The problem is that I cannot simply pull the cluth and restart the engine while I am moving but I have to brake and stop the car, then I can restart it. If I try to restart while the car has momentum it's a mess, the engine try to start a 3 cylinders and other terrible noises. It's quite dangerous. Probably it's because of an electronics management that I didn't had on other cars. I only drove manual transmission in the past 40 years and in the past 7 I drove the previous model of Triton without any problem. Thank you in advance if you can help me

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Review your owner's manual. There may be a new wrinkle of Mitsu diesel engines not allowing restarting while coasting until stopped. Or call your dealer since your '23 is under warranty.

I'm wondering how you stall an engine with the vehicle moving? And if you are moving, why not leave it in gear and pop the clutch.

Paulster2 This engine is quite different from the previous model, looks like there is not lorque at low rpm so it happens that while I am driving at low rpm if I put the wrong gear (for example 5 instead of3) the engine stops so I push the clutch and desengage the gear, the car continue moving by inertia but with a terrible sound (tactactac tac)​ so I have to brake and stop the car. Then I can restart the engine. If I try to restart the car while is still moving it's a disaster:looks like the engine try to start a 3 cylinder with huge vibrations.

The manual says you should have the brake on, clutch in, and be in neutral.  Certainly they could force any of these things to not allow the starter to spin if you aren't doing them.  These would all be easy to test.  Manufacturers did these things because people kept starting their cars with their foot on the gas not the brake and driving over or through things, then blaming the car company.
If the car is still rolling try this:  Put the car in 2nd and let out the clutch, the motion of the car should start it back up.
